# How can one input an arbitrary array to Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

The image below is the quadrotor model in simulink, now it's following a path made of sine waves for x and y.

If I want the quadrotor to follow a path made of predefined x,y,z values, how can I specify that?

[image: sl_quadrotor]

Comment: I see predefined `z=-4`. Can you made the `x` and `y` for the same way?

Comment: Yes I can do that, but then it is just one value. What I want to do is to define a "via-points" path. I want the quadrotor to follow a path of for example x,y,z: [ 1 1 0; 1 1 2; 1 1 4, 2 1 4 ... etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most logical way to do this is to create an arbitrary [timeseries](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html) variable in MATLAB and then use it as an input in Simulink using a "[Read data from workspace](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html?refresh=true)" block

Comment: That worked, thanks. I am plotting a polygon on a figure in the workspace, is it possible to let the quadrotor fly on the same figure on which I am plotting?